# Как получить дату изменения каталога в Java

Tags: java, файлы, io

Как в Java получить `Folder.lastModified()`? Вариант рекурсивного просмотра каталога в глубину и взятие даты последнего файла не подходит, так как каталог может быть пустым.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем так.
Дело в том, что если в родительском каталоге есть подкаталоги, то при изменениях в них, lastmodified родителя не меняется.
Поэтому, без рекурсии не обошлось:

```
    private static long getLatestModifiedDate(File dir) {
    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        long latestDate = 0;
        for (File file : files) {
            long fileModifiedDate = file.isDirectory()
                    ? getLatestModifiedDate(file) : file.lastModified();
            if (fileModifiedDate > latestDate) {
                latestDate = fileModifiedDate;
            }
        }
        return Math.max(latestDate, dir.lastModified());
    } else {
        return dir.lastModified();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Да вроде как так же, как и для любого файла:

```java
new Date(new File("C:\\Windows").lastModified()) // Sat Feb 10 04:20:29 MSK 2018
```